# Filter First drop down in SPService CASCADING dropdown

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am working on the Cascading Dropdowns for the Sharepoint.

I am able to implement this without any issue.

Now my problem is How to filter the First dropwdown Fill value using caml query.

E.g. I have list of projects and tasknames according to the Projects.

Projects is my first dropdown and according to the selection i am filling the second Task name  dropdown.
Now I want only those projects to be filled in First Dropdown which are active right now (Activew =Yes boolean column in list). How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem my own

For this I have to Use the Filtered LookUp column from SPServices.codeplex.com.

After adding this wsp in your Application you are able to create a Column as a Filtered lookup.

To Fulfill my desired result (Filter first Dropdown). I will Create one View in my List which will get only active projects from the list which i will bind to the first dropdown.

[Look at this Link](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)